# Как получить изображение под окном?

Tags: c++, delphi, windows, winapi

С помощью каких функций можно получить изображение под окном для последующего размытия и создания эффекта прозрачности а-ля OS X Yosemite? [image: Пример размытого фона в OS X Yosemite]

Похожее размытие в Windows 7 (однако `DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow` не подойдет из-за иного эффекта и отсутствия размытия в Windows 8.x)[image: Пример размытого фона в Windows 7]

Comment: Смотрю на [скриншот](http://cdn.osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/os-x-yosemite-desktop-apps.jpg) и не вижу размытия. О чём речь? Вы про толстую тень?

Comment: Каким образом тэги c++ и delphi оказались рядом? Определитесь, пожалуйста, на каком языке вы пишите. Кстати, неплохо было бы еще уточнить, вы пишите на "старом" delphi используя WinAPI и VCL - или же на "новом", используя .NET.

Comment: Я об [этом](http://habrastorage.org/files/863/d33/273/863d33273cac40c1847ea5b958e9e3cd.jpg) размытии.

Comment: @Pavel, пишу на Delphi, используя WinAPI и VCL, но примеры подойдут и на C++.

Comment: @khabibroman, внесите примеры в вопрос, иначе он непонятен для читающих.

Comment: Тогда нужен тэг winapi

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что получится. Есть программа Glass8, которая устанавливает хук на `SetWindowCompositionAttribute`  и `DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow` и реализует их на Windows 8. Как написано на сайте "All rendering is done via native Direct3D device.".
Читаем отзывы: `Прозрачная область размывается с дикими тормозами, тянется шлейф от стрелочки и всех объектов на заднем фоне.`. Оно вам надо?

Answer (score 1):

Средствами ОС Windows нельзя получить изображение под окном. Ибо она использует логику - "не хранить то что можно нарисовать заново" - есть левые костыли, но они глючные и не всюду работают. Так что будет очень непросто реализовать задумку.
Кстати на вашей [картинке](http://hsto.org/files/863/d33/273/863d33273cac40c1847ea5b958e9e3cd.jpg) нет никакого размытия, там вообще непрозрачное, если приглядеться.
Попробуйте что ли поискать как делают Shell-оболочки.

Answer (score 0):

В Delphi можно использовать свойства AlphaBlend

```
procedure TAboutBox.FormClose
(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
var
  i, cavb : 0..255;
begin
  if AlphaBlend=False then
  begin
    AlphaBlendValue:=255;
    AlphaBlend:=True;
  end;
  cavb:=AlphaBlendValue;

  for i := cavb downto 0 do
  begin
    AlphaBlendValue := i;
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  end
end;
```