# Как захватить область экрана, находящуюся под окном?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi, blur

Здравствуйте! Мне нужно получить изображение под окном, чтобы размыть и получить блюр, как в Fluent Design или OS X. В общем-то то же самое спрашивается здесь: [Как получить изображение под окном?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420260/195861) . Там сошлись на том, что это анриал.

У меня есть только один вариант, как это реализовать -

Окно с `WS_EX_LAYERED` -> установка прозрачного цвета -> в отрисовке первым делом на всё окно рисуется прямоугольник прозрачного цвета - получаем то что находится под окном -> создаём совместный контекст -> совместный битмап -> размываем битмап -> остальная прорисовка

Подойдёт ли такой способ? Какие есть ещё варианты?

Comment: Зачем вы хотите идти наперекор рекомендациям по графическому дизайну Windows? Причём настолько радикально, что приходится воевать с операционной системой. Даже если вы и победите её, единственное чего добьётесь — ваше приложение будет выглядеть чужеродно и выбиваться из общего визуального стиля.

Comment: @Arhad, 1) что за рекомендации? 2) потому что так красиво

Comment: Ну можно покопать в сторону [UWP и их размытого Acrylic фона](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/acrylic) или поглядеть на работу [Direct Composition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj553433(v=vs.85).aspx).